# How to assgin values to columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In picture it show clear i have dataframe with mentioned columns and data. Now how can i assign this data to columns.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f768i.png). if you look at the picture it will be more clear.

I try differen assigning operation but it show error like shape of passed values. I expecting that data(array) value to columns

Comment: Pictures are not reproducible, please provide a fully reproducible example as text

Answer (score 0):

*Please refrain from adding code in the form of an image, it's hard to access. [Here's an article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) explaining why.*

Create a new dataframe (although you can choose to modify the existing one) with the column names and the data. I have inferred that your array is stored in a variable named `data`.

```
df_updated = pd.DataFrame(data, df.columns)
```

Note: Thanks to [Timus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14311263/timus) for suggesting the removal of redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem you face is that there are many columns in the DataFrame and the Array contains values for some but not all of these columns. Hence your problem with shape when you try and combine the two. What you need to do is define the column names for the values in the data Array before combining the two. See example code below which forms another DataFrames with the correct column names and then finally joins things together.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [1.0, 2.0],
                    'b': [3.0, 5.0],
                    'c': [4.0, 7.0]
                    })

data = [1.1, 2.1]
names = ['a', 'b']
df2 = pd.DataFrame({key : val for key, val in zip(names, data)}, index= [0])

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop = True)
print(df3)
```

this produces

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  3.0  4.0
1  2.0  5.0  7.0
2  1.1  2.1  NaN
```

with NaN for the columns that were missing in the data to be added. You can change the NaN to any value you want using `fillna`

Comment: Thanks. but if i create new dataframe with selected columns. but i have huge amount of data how can i assign correct data to correct columns because right now i read data from file and data show in array mean in list

Comment: mean it work and assign data to selected columns but the data from different sensor. this is real data from wind turbine from different sensor. i want to assign wind sensor data to wind columns

Comment: Only you know which columns you want to assign data to and whether these are existing columns or new columns. The code follows from that. It would be very useful for you to produce a **minimal** example which exemplifies your issues - showing just some of the original dataframe, some of the data to be added and show how this changes the dataframe when added.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Basically the data we use in binary data because of huge amount of data. Funny thing First day First project